# Celery dynamic workflows

Tags: python, celery

I am using `Celery` version `3.1.17`.

Normally you can prepare your own static workflows with celery with canvas modules like `chain`, `group`, `chord` or simply `linking tasks`. You can access any result or any task property like task id of any task in your workflow. You have to have your tasks are predefined.

I am doing dynamic sub tasking by calling sub tasks in my workflow. For example, I call a task maybe a canvas module, and they decide the logic dynamically and try to call sub tasks according to that decision. But in that solution, there is no parent/child relation between my static workflow tasks and dynamic subtasks. I can not track them. This is really frustrating. Here is my current unusable way;

```
class ParentTask(Task):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SubTask().subtask(args=(1, 2), countdown=1).apply_async()

class SubTask(Task):
    def run(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        return x+y

non_tracable_for_subtask_result = ParentTask().delay()
```

I need a canvas module (group, chord etc.) can be extendable dynamically in a task in my  workflow. Can I link new sub tasks dynamically to my current workflow(`chord,group, etc.`) on runtime?
I want something like;

```
// THIS CODE DOES NOT WORK, JUST TO EXPLAIN REQUIREMENT
class ParentTask(Task):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        count = get_count()
        sub_task=SubTask().subtask(args=(1, 2), countdown=1)
        for i in range(count):
            //It could be like. THIS PART WHAT I LOOK FOR
            self.link(sub_task)

class SubTask(Task):
    def run(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        return x+y

>>> tracable_for_subtask_result = ParentTask().delay()
>>> tracable_for_subtask_result.children.get()
3
>>> tracable_for_subtask_result.children.id
.....
```

Comment: I could be wrong but as the `group` task is nothing more than a message that gets sent out I believe it is immutable at that time.  However with that being said it may be possible to read in that task and spawn a new group task including the old group and whatever you need to add

Comment: I actually need a tree structure which can be added some leafs when it is currently being processed (dynamic workflow). When I call a task, celery return a result which I can track somethings on it. But I need to get all leaf status and properties from that result. My question is to have a way to do that, not to do this with group or something else. I looked for it for a while and I couldn't find a way to do it. I hope, you are right and there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can express dynamic workflows using `task.replace`.
There are some examples here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3437

You can write something like:

```
class ParentTask(Task):
def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
    count = get_count()
    sub_tasks=[subtask.s(i) for i in range(count)]
    g = group(*sub_tasks) | after_sub_tasks.s(self.request.id).on_error(after_sub_tasks_error.s(self.request.id))
    return self.replace(g) # current task is replaced with subtasks without blocking current worker

@app.task(bind=True, name='after_sub_task')
def after_sub_tasks.(self, results, main_task_id):
    print(f"results {results}")
    print(f"main_task_id {main_task_id}")
    return True

@app.task(bind=True, name='nx.delayed_task_error')
def after_sub_tasks_error(self, failed_task_id, main_task_id):
    # no results available here... sigh
    print(f"main_task_id {main_task_id}")
    raise ValueError("Part of subtasks failed")
```